# Content search query sort

Tags: content-search-web-part, search-query

I am trying to show last 10 modified documents in my search query for content search web part. 
In my query for sorting i choose "LastModifiedTime" descending. But the query dont display the correct sort. How come?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/why-are-my-sort-orders-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-2013-search-results-web-part#.VWwH-0aLE_w).

Solution from linked post:

> One solution to this problem would be to create a result source with
>   the query and sorting. You can then configure the Web Part to use that
>   result source. You’d have to manage this outside of your Web Part, so
>   if you don’t feel like adding the overhead of a result source and want
>   all the configuration contained within the web part itself, there is
>   another solution.
>
> The solution is to have the JSON sort defined in the available sort
>   orders property in the Web Part. It’s not the most obvious setting but
>   if you don’t have this defined, your sorting won’t be applied.

Json sort example (from linked post)

```
[
   {
      "name":"Name and Location Sort",
      "sorts":[
         {
            "p":"Name",
            "d":0
         },
         {
            "p":"Location",
            "d":0
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> The “name” property is the display name that you will see in the
>   search drop down. Even though we’re not displaying the search drop
>   down in our Web Part you can still give it a meaningful name.
>
> The “sorts” property contains our sort order for the search results.
>   The “p” is the managed property name and the “d” defines whether
>   descending order is true or false (1 is descending and 0 is
>   ascending).